# Media Player Looping : Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am having 3 secs of mp3 file. I want to play that mp3 file continuously still the user click pause button. Is there any method to loop the single file and play it again again till user pauses it.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Comment: after call "player.stop"..did "player.start"...but it's not working ...any idea how to restart looping..?

Comment: once you call `stop()`, you have to call `prepare()/prepareAsync()` before calling `start()` again

Comment: How can i make it loop for 3 times only ??

Answer (score 10):

This is working on my projects, place mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); after mediaPlayer.start();

```
public static void PlayAudio(Context c, int id){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, id);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,50);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            isPlayingAudio = true;
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 3):

This is a working code that i used in my project

```
 if (Flags.notificationReceived) {
                        showAlert(Flags.patientModel);
                        Flags.notificationReceived = false;
                        mp.start();
                        mp.setLooping(true);
                        vibrate(2000);
                    }
```

Comment: stop looping by onclick same play

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me. (written in Kotlin)

```
 val uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
 var mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri)
 mp.isLooping = true
 mp.start()
```

For stop, you should call your `stop()` function:

```
mp.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`mediaPlayer.start()` for **starting** the mediaPlayer, `mediaPlayer.pause()` for **pausing** the mediaPlayer. For **looping** the ***mediaPlayer*** for number of times then you can use loop:-

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting this value in a for-loop?

Comment: to set the audio in loop according to user's choice, it's just an example not a perfect code.