# How do I loop a sound file infinitely in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-button

I have done a simple stopwatch app. I have **start** and **pause** button to *start* and *stop/pause* sound respectively.
Right now my buttons are able to start and stop sound. But since my sound file is 2 minutes long, it only plays 2 minutes and after that stops automatically.

Now, what I want is to keep playing the sound forever until the **pause** button is pressed.

```
private MediaPlayer mp;//is originally initialized inside the class but outside method
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
           mp.start();
          }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                mp.stop();

            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461270/media-player-looping-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

For song looping try using `mp.setLooping(true);` something like this:

`MediaPlayer mp;
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_song);
 mp.setLooping(true);`

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code and in this case explain where in context that code should be used.  Thanks

Comment: Yes is true but is an exmple however i am goig to correct it for better explanation.