# Sound stops when button is pressed again

Tags: java, android, audio

I m trying to make a android soundboard.When i touch any button it produces sound but when i touch it again, not only sound stops but none of the other button works.I want it play one sound at a time.Here is my main activity i m calling the play functions on buttons.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer whine, cry, weed, chup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        whine = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gone);
        cry = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mock);
        weed = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.phen);
        chup = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rg);
    }
    public void playwhine(View view) {
        if (cry.isPlaying())
            cry.stop();
        if (weed.isPlaying())
            weed.stop();
        if (chup.isPlaying())
            chup.stop();
        whine.start();
    }

    public void playcry(View view) {
        if (whine.isPlaying())
            whine.stop();
        if (weed.isPlaying())
            weed.stop();
        if (chup.isPlaying())
            chup.stop();
        cry.start();
    }

    public void playweed(View view) {
        if (cry.isPlaying())
            cry.stop();
        if (whine.isPlaying())
            whine.stop();
        if (chup.isPlaying())
            chup.stop();
        weed.start();
    }

    public void playchup(View view) {
        if (cry.isPlaying())
            cry.stop();
        if (whine.isPlaying())
            whine.stop();
        if (weed.isPlaying())
            weed.stop();
        chup.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample is taken from your last method:

```
public void playchup(View view) {
    if (cry.isPlaying())
        cry.stop();
    if (whine.isPlaying())
        whine.stop();
    if (weed.isPlaying())
        weed.stop();
    chup.start();
}
```

If you look at the last three if-statements you can see that you stop the sound. If any sound is playing it is stopped when the button is pressed.

Let me further explain:

1. Button is pressed
2. Call is made to one of the four methods(play())
3. You stop the other sounds
4. And play the sound for the related method

**Possible issue**

In theory, when the MediaPLayer is played through, you have to recreate it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461270/media-player-looping-android) to see how you can loop the sounds and not have to recreate the mediaplayer every single time.

Meaning your code should look like this:

```
whine = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gone);
cry = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mock);
weed = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.phen);
chup = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rg);

whine.setLooping(true);
cry.setLooping(true);
weed.setLooping(true);
chup.setLooping(true);
```

And if you don't want to stop every other sound when one button is pressed you have to remove the if-statements that check if other sounds are playing and stopping them.

**Alternative to MediaPlayer**

If you are dealing with several sounds you can use a [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) as it is designed to handle several and overlapping sounds at once.

Answer (score 0):

Because You are creating `MusicPlayer`objects but not **releasing** them

Declare a Interface and **override** `setOnCompletion`to call `release()` method.

**Example**

```
 private class musicCompletionListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
```

and Then setOnCompletion listener for each **mediaPlayer** objects.

```
public void playwhine(View view) {
    if (cry.isPlaying())
        cry.stop();
    if (weed.isPlaying())
        weed.stop();
    if (chup.isPlaying())
        chup.stop();
whine.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
    whine.start();
}

public void playcry(View view) {
    if (whine.isPlaying())
        whine.stop();
    if (weed.isPlaying())
        weed.stop();
    if (chup.isPlaying())
        chup.stop();
cry.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
    cry.start();
}

public void playweed(View view) {
    if (cry.isPlaying())
        cry.stop();
    if (whine.isPlaying())
        whine.stop();
    if (chup.isPlaying())
        chup.stop();
weed.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
    weed.start();
}

public void playchup(View view) {
    if (cry.isPlaying())
        cry.stop();
    if (whine.isPlaying())
        whine.stop();
    if (weed.isPlaying())
        weed.stop();
chup.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
    chup.start();
}
```